# Unable to parse a Date from a String in Java (java.text.ParseException)

Tags: java, date, locale, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a String describing a date (in french) :

```
String dateAParser="dim 6 janv 2013 07:40:00";

    SimpleDateFormat parseur = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRENCH);
    try{
        Date dateAllerDepart= new Date();
        dateAllerDepart=parseur.parse(dateAParser);

        System.out.println(dateAllerDepart);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

It gives me these errors :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dim 6 janv 2013 07:40:00"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at TestAvecJsoup.main(TestAvecJsoup.java:109)
```

I think my SimpleDateFormat object is ok, and I searched and tried a lot of things to solve this problem, so I hope you will give some clues on how to solve it.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to parse: String dateAParser="dim 06 janv 2013 07:40:00";

Comment: @MrSmith42 Doesn't work, throws the same exception.

Comment: Also a good test is using the `SimpleDateFormat` to format a `Date` (better if it is with your expected value) into `String` and see which is the output.

Comment: Try only parts of the date String and the corresponding part of the format string. This way you can find out, what part leads to the problem.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I tried that : it seems this is the "dim 06 janv 2013" which is faulty, but I can't say more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two minor changes, adding periods after the abbreviations, and using 3 Ms instead of 4:

```
    final String dateAParser = "dim. 6 janv. 2013 07:40:00";
    final SimpleDateFormat parseur = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRENCH);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of date String "dim" and month seems to be the issue here, are you sure it's correct value?

This works fine.

```
        String dateAParser="06 2013 07:40:00 AM";

        SimpleDateFormat parseur = new SimpleDateFormat("dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.FRENCH);
```

Comment: for abbreviation, you need to add period as explained by Charlie.